# Ubuntu ARM install of ROS Indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install ros indigo on Odroid U3. Following the instructions in wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM. In point 2.5 when I'm trying to update I get the following error:
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
E: The list of sources could not be read
I have no idea wants going wrong. Someone who can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200093/ubuntu-arm-install-of-ros-indigo/) by [Arcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21243/arcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're misspelled `deb` as `dep`.

You should correct your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` so that it contains:

```
deb http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros trusty main
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1